# Entity framework not generating the database classes

Tags: entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019 I recently upgraded all my NuGet packages, so I see that EntityFramework is now showing as 6.2.0.  My project is a Web API 2 solution.  When I open my database model and right-click to *Update Model from Database* I can select my new tables but when I save the edmx file it closes immediately.  In the past it would run for a bit while it wrote new files.

In the actual `.edmx` file itself for example I see this entry for my newly added table:

```xml
<EntityType Name="Audit_Log">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="id" />
  </Key>
  <Property Name="id" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="Lab_Space_Id" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="Field" Type="varchar" MaxLength="80" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="Old_Value" Type="varchar" MaxLength="1000" />
  <Property Name="New_Value" Type="varchar" MaxLength="1000" />
  <Property Name="Modified" Type="datetime2" Precision="7" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="Updater" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
</EntityType>
```

However, it didn't generate the corresponding class definition for the Audit_Log class.  If I completely remove the edmx file and select all my desired tables plus this new one it will generate it correctly.

Comment: I had the same bug too. EDMX and Visual Studio 2019 are not having a great time. I had to return to Visual Studio 2017 mainly for that reason. Fortunately, you can have both installations on your machine. My problem was even worse. When I wanted to update a table, my project would compile tons of errors asking me to add the namespace before every model reference. (Vb.NET)

Comment: Probably something to do with automatic code generation on save. Maybe not enabled by default in VS2019?

Comment: @MichaëlCorriveau-Côté See my posted workaround if you want to keep using VS 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **workaround** for the problem.  If you expand the `.edmx` file in Solution Explorer you'll see two files that end in `.tt`.  Right-click on those and choose to *Run Custom Tool* and then the classes will be generated.  Just doing it on the `.edmx` file itself didn't work for me.